# An error occurred while install extend cpp

Tags: pytorch, extension-methods

I want to use this repository that url is https://github.com/vt-vl-lab/flownet2.pytorch in my project,but when I run the

```
bash install.sh
```

then got the ImportError: torch.utils.ffi is deprecated. Please use cpp extensions instead.

Maybe use an older version of pytorch will solve the problem,but I want run it at pytorch version 1.10.1,I try to transform the build.py to cpp_extension with

```
setup(
    name = '_ext.correlation',
    ext_modules=[
        CUDAExtension(
            name='_ext.correlation',
            sources=['src/correlation_cuda.c','correlation_cuda_kernel.cu']
        )
    ],
    cmdclass={
        'build_ext':BuildExtension
    }
)
```

then edit the make.sh

```
PYTHON=${PYTHON:-"python"}
TORCH=$($PYTHON -c "import os; import torch; print(os.path.dirname(torch.__file__))")

cd src

echo "Compiling correlation kernels by nvcc..."


nvcc -c -o correlation_cuda_kernel.o correlation_cuda_kernel.cu -x cu -Xcompiler -fPIC -arch=sm_30
rm correlation_cuda_kernel.o
rm -r ../_ext
cd ../
#$PYTHON build.py build
$PYTHON build.py install
```

then got the error: Invalid distribution name or version syntax: -ext.correlation-0.0.0

How can I fix it?

And have an other problem at

```
rm -r ../_ext
```

rm: cannot remove '../_ext': No such file or directory